# Node remains in commissioning status

Tags: maas

I have been trying to set up ubuntu cloud 12.04.  I'm kind of new to MAAS and ubuntu.

Here is what I followed.

1. Have installed MAAS server using the steps provided in
   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS
2. For the node, I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 Server Image on a USB Stick. Then restarted the node and opted to enlist the node via boot
   media, with PXE. once the process was done, the node was powered off
   as expected. I manually powered on the node, as my node is not PXE
   enabled. Result - No node was visible on MAAS UI

   1. Since step 2 didn't work, I added the node via maas-cli.  command. After the execution of this command I got the
      node reflected on to my MAAS UI. But the status continues to be in
      "Commissioning" for a long time.
   2. Then I executed "maas-cli maas nodes check-commissioning " and i got "Unrecognised signature: POST check_commissioning".

I'm not sure where is the error. Could some one please help me solve this issue. I checked the following log file but found no error related to commissioning (pserv.log / maas.log / celery.log/celery-region.log). I found this entry in my auth.log "Nov 16 18:20:34 ubuntuCloud sshd[4222]: Did not receive identification string from xxx.xx.xx.x" not sure if it indicates anything as the ip that is mentioned is not of the node nor of the MAAS server.

I also verified the time on the server and node using date cmd - (at one instance the times are : Server: Fri Nov 16 18:15:51 IST 2012 and Node Fri Nov 16 18:15:43 IST 2012). Not sure if 'date' the right cmd to set the time.

I have also check maas_local_settings.py for the MAAS url.

I'm not sure what are the logs that need to be verified. Is there any log that can be checked on the Node.

Thanks
Vinitha

---

I kind of figured out what is going wrong. I had missed setting the entry in DHCP server to point to MAAS Server. But my question now is, I'm trying to set the cloud environment within the LAN, and we already have a DHCP Server in the network and I will not be able to have my own DHCP server nor can I modify the existing DHCP server to point to MAAS Server.  Is there a possibility of having a MAAS setup with in an existing LAN ?. Any link / workaround to this would be of great help.

Thanks
Vinitha

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am doing to get around this:
Setup the MAAS master node as dual homed. In other words, install another network card in it.
Run your DHCP server so that it only listens and answers in your cluster network.
connect a switch to the MAAS master node, and connect all your other nodes to that.

Does that help at all?